# OpenGL picking - Ray/sphere intersection wrong

Tags: c++, opengl

I have problem with my ray picking code. My code

I am using this code for picking calulation:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------
Function:   GetViewportSystem
Returns:
    viewportCoordSystem

Get viewport coordinate system (only for reading)
Forward ray goes through origin
-------------------------------------------------------------*/
ViewportCoordSystem Camera::GetViewportSystem() const
{
    ViewportCoordSystem viewportCoord;
    viewportCoord.w = this->cameraPos;
    viewportCoord.w -= this->lookAt;
    viewportCoord.w.Normalize();

    viewportCoord.u = MyMath::Vector3::Cross(MyMath::Vector3::UnitY(), viewportCoord.w);

    viewportCoord.v = MyMath::Vector3::Cross(viewportCoord.w, viewportCoord.u);

    float d = (this->viewport.Height / 2.0f) * (1.0f / tanf(this->viewport.fov / 2.0f));
    viewportCoord.origin = this->cameraPos;
    viewportCoord.origin -= d * viewportCoord.w;

    return viewportCoord;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------
Function:   MapViewport2Dto3D
Parametrs:
    [in] viewportSystem - cameras viewport coordinate system
    [in] point - 2D point on image
Returns:
    3D mapped point in space

Map 2D image point to 3D space
Info about mapping 2D to 3D: http://meatfighter.com/juggler/
-------------------------------------------------------------*/
MyMath::Vector3 Camera::MapViewport2Dto3D(const ViewportCoordSystem & viewportSystem, const MyMath::Vector2 & point) const
{
    MyMath::Vector3 res = viewportSystem.origin;
    res += (point.X - this->viewport.Width * 0.5f) * viewportSystem.u;
    res += (this->viewport.Height * 0.5f - point.Y) * viewportSystem.v;
    return res;
}
```

Picking itself

```
ViewportCoordSystem vpSystem = this->camera->GetViewportSystem();
MyMath::Vector3 pos = this->camera->MapViewport2Dto3D(vpSystem, MyMath::Vector2(mouseX, mouseY));

this->ray.dir = pos - this->camera->GetPosition();
this->ray.dir.Normalize();

this->ray.origin = this->camera->GetPosition();
```

With this ray, I calculate ray - sphere intersection test.

```
bool BoundingSphere::RayIntersection(const MyMath::Ray & ray) const
{
    MyMath::Vector3 Q = this->sphereCenter - ray.origin;
    double c = Q.LengthSquared();
    double v = MyMath::Vector3::Dot(Q, ray.dir);
    double d = this->sphereRadius * this->sphereRadius - (c - v * v);

    if (d < 0.0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Problem is, that my code works incorrect. If I visualuse my spheres, and click inside them, I got correct answer only for half of the sphere. When I move camera, than its all messed up and picking reacts outside spheres.
My world is not transformed (all world matrices are Identity). Only camera is moving. I calculate mouse position within OpenGL window correctly (upper left corner has [0, 0] and goes to [width, height]).

PS: I am using this code succesfully in DirectX for raycasting / raytracing. And I cant see anything wrong with it. My OpenGL renderer is using Left-Handed system (its not natural for OpenGL, but I want it that way)

**Edit:**
After visualizing the ray, problem is apearing, when I mov cameraleft / right. Center of ray is not cohherent with mouse position.

Comment: Try rendering the pick ray? Maybe it'll help you figure out if it's an issue with the ray/sphere intersection, or with computing the ray itself

Comment: My "engine" can not render lines :(

Comment: @MartinPerry can it draw a very thin and long box/cylinder?  If so render that!

Comment: Which half of the sphere is it working/failing on?

Comment: @Kirk Backus.. it seems for left part. But If I move camera, then its messed up completly and test is true outside sphere.

Comment: @Drew McGowen I have created ray... ray-sphere is OK, but my Ray is not always "under" cursor position. If I move camera left / right, camera ismoving faster than ray start position, so mouse cursor is "ahead" of ray start.... eh

Comment: That's expected - the cursor moves right when you move the mouse, but it takes a bit of time for that motion info to propagate through the GUI and into your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.. found the problem... for anybody else, who might be interessted

Those wo lines are incorrect

```
viewportCoord.u = MyMath::Vector3::Cross(MyMath::Vector3::UnitY(), viewportCoord.w);
viewportCoord.v = MyMath::Vector3::Cross(viewportCoord.w, viewportCoord.u);
```

Working solution is

```
viewportCoord.u = MyMath::Vector3::Cross(viewportCoord.w, MyMath::Vector3::UnitY());
viewportCoord.u.Normalize();
viewportCoord.v = MyMath::Vector3::Cross(viewportCoord.u, viewportCoord.w);
viewportCoord.v.Normalize();
```